# MongoDB - specify that collection may only contain one document

Tags: mongodb

I would like to create a special MongoDB collection called "status" and I want to specify that it may only contain one document.  Under no circumstances do I want this collection to contain more than one document.  Is this possible?

Comment: You could possibly use a capped collection that is limited to 1. Never tried it. Problem with that would be it could contain only 1 at a time, but not always the same document. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/

Comment: Thanks - looking into this approach right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via unique index. For example:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.unique.insert({a:1})
rs0:PRIMARY> db.unique.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547e2c8c9678b5b7ab75a014"), "a" : 1 }
rs0:PRIMARY> db.unique.ensureIndex({b:1}, {unique:true})
rs0:PRIMARY> db.unique.insert({a:2})
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.unique.$b_1  dup key: { : null }
```

Add a unique index on any field that you know will NEVER be part of your schema. (in this example 'b') Then it will be indexed to null, preventing any other null items from being insert. It'll throw an exception in your app-code when it tries to insert.

Comment: Nice way of doing it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to put a cap on a collection for both collection size and number of documents by using [Capped Collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/).

This is how you can create a capped collection:

```
db.createCollection("log", { capped : true, size : 5000, max : 1 } )
```

This collection will always have size less than 5000 and can only contain 1 document.

Note that, capped collections work in a way similar to circular buffers: once a collection fills its allocated space, it makes room for new documents by overwriting the oldest documents in the collection.